# Align the button in Wavesurfer-react waveform- button should be down on the waveform

Tags: reactjs, waveform, wavesurfer.js

both button is after the 2 waveform, I want waveform and then the button under on that waveform, same with the other one

[image]

Can somebody help me with the alignment of the button, on the photo, you see that the button for the first is together with the second button, that should not be the behavior, the button should be after the waveform , and same with the second waveform

Here's my code:

```
code here

import React, { useCallback, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { WaveSurfer, WaveForm } from "wavesurfer-react";

import RegionsPlugin from "wavesurfer.js/dist/plugins/regions";

const Buttons = styled.button`

      display: inline-block;
`;

const Button = styled.button``;

function Waves() {


 const plugins = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        plugin: RegionsPlugin,
        options: {
          dragSelection: false
        }
      }
    ].filter(Boolean);
  }, []);

  const wavesurferRef = useRef();



  const handleWSMount = useCallback((waveSurfer) => {
    if (waveSurfer.markers) {
      waveSurfer.clearMarkers();
    }

    wavesurferRef.current = waveSurfer;

    if (wavesurferRef.current) {
      wavesurferRef.current.load('../../soundsgenere/rocktwo.mp3');

      wavesurferRef.current.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("WaveSurfer is ready");
      });

      wavesurferRef.current.on("region-removed", (region) => {
        console.log("region-removed --> ", region);
      });

      wavesurferRef.current.on("loading", (data) => {
        console.log("loading --> ", data);
      });

      if (window) {
        window.surferidze = wavesurferRef.current;
          }
        }
      }, []);

      const play = useCallback(() => {
        wavesurferRef.current.playPause();
      }, []);

      const next = useCallback(() => {
        wavesurferRef.current.skipForward();
      }, []);

      const back = useCallback(() => {
        wavesurferRef.current.skipBackward();
      }, []);

  return (
    
<div className="wav">
   
    <WaveSurfer
        plugins={plugins}
        onMount={handleWSMount}
        progressColor="#DB2C3B"
        barWidth={2.67}
        barGap={4}
       
      >     
        <WaveForm id="waveform" cursorColor="transparent" />
          
      </WaveSurfer>
       <Buttons>
        <Button onClick={play}>Play / Pause</Button>
      </Buttons>
           
      <WaveSurfer
        plugins={plugins}
        onMount={handleWSMount}
        progressColor="#DB2C3B"
        barWidth={2.67}
        barGap={4}
       
      >
     
        <WaveForm id="waveform" cursorColor="transparent" />
          
      </WaveSurfer>
       <Buttons>
        <Button onClick={play}>Play / Pause</Button>
      </Buttons>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default Waves;
```

I want the button after each waveform.

Comment: To all viewing this, to see the photo, kindly click the underline link on the top -'both button is after the 2 waveform, I want waveform and then the button under on that waveform, same with the other one'

Answer (score 0):

Ive already fix this, we have to call the id of the audio or song that on the waveform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).